# Problems getting onDOMContentLoaded to trigger on Chrome Extension (manifest v3)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**Goal:** a chrome extension that injects a script every time a user loads a youtube video in the browser (triggered when the youtube video page finishes loading). The script injected hides the video overlay present when a cursor is over the video or when the video is paused)

**Problem:** nothing executes inside my chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener, the console.log doesn't print anything on the console. Where is my gap in understanding?

I have read dozens of similar questions on SO to no avail (most of which use manifest V2).

Here's what I have so far:
**manifest.json**

```
{
   "background": {
      "service_worker":  "src/background.js"
   },
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [ "src/hide.js"],
      "matches": [ "http://*.youtube.com/watch?*", "https://*.youtube.com/watch?*" ]
   } ],
   "description": "Hide YouTube video player overlay",
   "icons": {
      "128": "img/icon128.png",
      "16": "img/icon16.png",
      "32": "img/icon32.png",
      "48": "img/icon48.png"
   },
   "manifest_version": 3,
   "name": "hideYTOverlay",
   "permissions": [ "activeTab", "scripting", "webNavigation"],
   "version": "1.0"
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {

chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(async ({ tabId, url }) => {
    console.log("hello hello!")
    if (url.includes("youtube.com/watch?")){ 
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId },
        files: ['src/hide.js']
    });
}
});
});
```

**hide.js**

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-chrome-top')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-chrome-bottom')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-gradient-top')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youtube is a SPA (single-page application) site, so it loads just once, then fakes URL navigation and changes DOM of the same page document, which is why there's no more DOMContentLoaded events.

While the problem can be solved by using a different event such as [onHistoryStateUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webNavigation/#event-onHistoryStateUpdated) (you'll also have to [remove onInstalled event](/a/57472453)), but all your modifications are pure CSS, so you can greatly simplify the extension and improve its performance.

1. Remove `background`, `permissions`, `js` from manifest.json, delete background.js and hide.js
2. Add `css` for the entire site (because youtube is a SPA):

```json
 "content_scripts": [{
   "css": ["youtube.css"],
   "matches": ["*://www.youtube.com/*"],
   "run_at": "document_start"
 }],
```

3. Create `youtube.css` file:

```css
.ytp-chrome-top,
.ytp-chrome-bottom,
.ytp-gradient-top {
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

If you want to be able to toggle the CSS by clicking the extension's icon you'll need `"action":{}, "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"]` in manifest.json and the `background` service worker like this:

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    func: () => document.body.classList.toggle('jlo-allow'),
  }).catch(() => {});
});
```

and youtube.css like this:

```css
body:not(.jlo-allow) :is(.ytp-chrome-top, .ytp-chrome-bottom, .ytp-gradient-top) {
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks! Would this css-only approach allow for disabling css changes upon clicking on the extension icon? (detected with a chrome.action.onClicked.addListener) Or would that again require a sw.js that triggers a script that handles that particular case? (i.e. to grey out the icon and disable css changes)